# CakePHP - Default labels to placeholders instead

Tags: cakephp, placeholder, label

So, in CakePHP, there is a way to turn off labels by default by putting `'label'=>false` in 'inputDefaults' in the `Form->create()` statement.

Is there a way to, instead of removing labels altogether, to change labels into element placeholder attributes?  This is equivalent to doing the `'inputDefaults'=>array('label'=>false)` on the `Form->create` while adding a `'placeholder'=>'Placeholder'` to each element... but is there a way to do it without having to add it to each element and have CakePHP do it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run your own copy of FormHelper that contains your modifications. You can copy the version of FormHelper from lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php and paste it into your app at app/View/Helper/FormHelper.php and make the required modifications to your copy. The copy in your app folder takes precedence over the one provided in the core. As always, never ever **ever** make modifications to files in Core.

Alternatively, you could extend FormHelper into your own Helper class:

```
class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper {
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to add 'MyForm' into your $helpers array!

At any rate, what you're asking is not currently possible using Cake 2.x. Without any changes, you'll need to add a 'placeholder' => '...' in the options array of each input() call. If you make this change, please consider contributing it back to the CakePHP community so others can benefit from your work!